# Should I use one WebView per element in a ListView, or a single WebView, and add and remove elements with JavaScript called from native Android code?

Tags: android, android-webview, google-cloud-messaging

My goal is to be able to define most of my UI through HTML server-side, yet still take advantage of many native features, such as Google Cloud Messaging.

Specifically, upon receiving a GCM message, I need to add or remove an element from a list in the UI. The Element will be a complete interactive widget, rather than just some text, and will involve simple AJAXy communications with a server, but will never need to be reloaded itself (ie it isn't intended to be a browsable webpage). I can see two obvious options for this:

- Use a ListView, and have each element be a fixed height WebView with no scrolling, and use WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL() to insert the HTML from the GCM payload.
- Use a WebView and build the list and full UI behaviour in HTML/css/js, loading it with WebView.loadUrl(), and then each time a GCM message is received, call WebView.loadUrl("javascript:myUpdateFunction(\""+data-to-display+"\")" to pass in JSON data from the GCM payload.

I am concerned that the ListView with many WebViews will be too slow. On the upside, each WebView can have its own HTML, and there's no concerns about one GCM call affecting the other elements. In my mind, this is simpler, and less error-prone, as I can benefit from the built-in logic of ListView.

I am concerned that the WebView with explicit calls from native to JavaScript will be error-prone because I'll need to manage all the adding and removing of elements myself. On the upside, I could trigger a refresh of the entire page relatively easily.

Any recommendations or other options?